# Resource не найден

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, extension

У меня есть ресурс:

```
<local:SharedResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources"
                              xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <sys:String x:Key="Text">Text</sys:String>
</local:SharedResourceDictionary>
```

Это ресурс для текста метки (да, так можно). Но дело не в этом. Есть расширение разметки:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace MyApp
{
    using static ResourceManager;

    public class SomeResourceExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        [ConstructorArgument("resourceKey")]
        public object ResourceKey { get; set; }

        public SomeResourceExtension(object resourceKey = null) => ResourceKey = resourceKey ?? "";

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => GetElement(ResourceKey);
    }
}
```

Что за классы `SharedResourceDictionary` и `SomeResourceExtension`? О первом можно прочитать вот [тут](https://www.wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html). А второе это "зацензуренный" (в вопросе `SomeResourceExtension`, а в проекте `ThemeResourceExtension`) настоящий класс. Но это не важно - они идеально работают. Так в чём проблема? Дело в том, что в конструкторе Visual Studio мне выдает ошибку aka `Ресурс resources/default.xaml не найден`. Но при запуске всё работает. Т. е. при прекомпиляции в конструкторе выдает ошибку, что ресурс не нашло, а при запуске приложения всё ок. Что не так? Если что uri ресурса `pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Resources/Default.xaml`.

---

Как решить это проблему?

### UPD

Код окна:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:res="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{res:SomeResource Text}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: `У меня есть ресурс:` Где он есть? Какие свойства выставлены для него? Как он компилируется?

Comment: Причина проста: дизайнер студии недостаточно интеллектуален чтобы отследить всю цепочку

Comment: @ヒミコ я пробовал все действия при сборке (Page, встроенный ресурс, компиляция и т. д.), но результат такой же. А так настройки абсолютно стандартные.

Comment: @АндрейNOP А жаль. Ведь это так не удобно, что я не могу видеть свои результаты в конструкторе(

Comment: @return, жаль, но, судя по всему, MS дизайнер давно уже не развивает